# What am i doing wrong ? I am a beginner in js

Tags: javascript, html

This is what they want us exactly to do :

Create a page (+ JavaScript) where it will implement a simple adder, i.e. you will type numbers in a Text Box and with the click of a button they will be added to the total that will be displayed in a second Text Box.

In case the total sum exceeds 1000 a message is displayed.

I ve already tried this but no matter what i try to do it doesnt seem to work. I would appriciate some help

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" value="0"/>
    <button onclick="AddNumbers()">Add</button>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" value="0"/>
    
    <script>
        function AddNumbers() {
            var t1 = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
            var t2 = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
            var sum = parseFloat("t1").value + parseFloat("t2").value ;
            if (sum > 1000){
                window.alert("Over 1000");
            } else {
                t2=sum;
                document.getElementById("txt2").innerHTML=t2;
            }     
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Besides hints on what a halfway proper question title should be phrased like, it also explains how to give a _proper_ problem description; "doesnt seem to work" isn't one.

Comment: it should just be `parseFloat(t1)` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: `"t1"` is a literal string with two characters. You don't want that, you want the *variable* with that name. Drop those quotes.

Comment: `var sum = parseFloat(t1) + parseFloat(t2);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some of the comments mentioned, your errors are on this line:

```
var sum = parseFloat("t1").value + parseFloat("t2").value ;
```

You need to take the variable t1 and t2 which are already the (stringified) numbers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txt1" value="0"/>
    <button onclick="AddNumbers()">Add</button>
    <input type="text" id="txt2" value="0"/>
    
    <script>
        function AddNumbers() {
            var t1 = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
            var t2 = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
            var sum = parseFloat(t1) + parseFloat(t2);
            if (sum > 1000){
                window.alert("Over 1000");
            } else {
                t2=sum;
                document.getElementById("txt2").value=t2;
            }     
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, as you wrote this, its trying to replace the content of the second input with the answer. You should probably make a third element which can hold the result of the addition on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Put the result in #txt2 is not a good idea because if you do it you lose #txt2.
Next, you shouldn't use `.innerHTML` on a input to change it's value but `.value = x`.
If you want to display the sum in HTML create a new tag that will receive .innerHTML

`parseFloat` is called on a variable, so use it like : `parseFlot(t1)` and not `parseFloat("t1")`. Then, t1 is a string so you doesn't have to call `.value`

```html
<body>
    <input type="number" id="nb1" value="0" />
    <span>+</span>
    <input type="number" id="nb2" value="0" />
    <button onclick="AddNumbers()">=</button>
    <span id="result3"></span>

    <script>
        function AddNumbers() {
            var t1 = document.getElementById("nb1").value;
            var t2 = document.getElementById("nb2").value;
            var sum = parseFloat(t1) + parseFloat(t2);
            if (sum > 1000) {
                window.alert("Over 1000");
            } else {
                t2 = sum;
                document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = t2;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> variable t1 and t2 have assigned with value of the textbox , so simply add the variable.
> to set the value in textbox , you need to use .value = 'someValue', innerHTML - used to add/append DOM Element into the target element

> Try the below code , it might help you

```
function AddNumbers() {
        var t1 = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
        var t2 = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
        var sum = parseFloat(t1) + parseFloat(t2) ;
        if (sum > 1000){
            window.alert("Over 1000");
        } else {
            t2=sum;
            document.getElementById("txt2").value=t2;
        }     
    }
```